# Duplicate entry in Music database

Tags: automator, music, macos

Sometimes I find that an album shows two copies of the same song.  All the metadata is the same, and they actually both point to the same file.  (Not to a "file.mp3" and a separate "file 1.mp3")

I'd like a way to automate removal of one of every such entry without deleting the actual file.  Currently, all I know is Get Info on both (to verify File is the same), then delete, confirm, and click Keep File.

Comment: I also find _predefined_ playlist appearing twice.  I delete one, and the next time /i look, it's there twice again.  These are playlists that come with the system, that I did not create, and that I do not use.  "Recently played" and "Top 25"

Answer (score 1):

I've been suffering the same issues lately, stemming from a patchy import of my files into a new Music library on a new MBP (Monterey 12.5 on M1). Before you ask I did not have an existing library in any fit state to import, so I have been piecing together my collection from multiple sources. I've been several years away from Macs as a daily machine.

During the troubleshooting phase I've found (so far) the following 3 scenarios for duplicate entries in the Music database. Now, let me mention I am also using iTunes Match which also does some weird things with files and database entries! YMMV.

#### Possible Scenarios

1. Duplicate entries with identical metadata but each entry points to a different file eg. `01 song.m4a` and `01 song 1.m4a`. This appears to be the result of the same source file being imported twice. This is the scenario you are excluding in the question, but I am including here for completeness.
2. What *appear* to be duplicate entries at first glance based on metadata in the song or album views, but when the metadata is examined `Cmd-I` you find that the entries point to different files, *and* the metadata is different because characters unsupported in filenames has been used to populate the tags. E.g. an apostrophe may be translated into an underscore. In that situation Music is clever enough to re-translate it to an apostrophe for display. This is quite a common issue, but tricky to spot.
3. Duplicate entries that seem to be caused by some sort of hiccup. The metadata is identical and both entries point to the same file. This fits the bill for your question, and is the one most troubling for me. Oddly the duplicate usually only appears in Song view, not in Album view.

#### Potential Solutions

1. **Dupes with different filenames.**

   I've used two methods:

   1. `Get Info (Cmd-I)` each entry to identify the rogue filename and delete. Note, I have found in this scenario Music gives you the option to either `Bin` or `Keep` the file. I find this behaviour rather strange, as if you try to delete any other track that is not duplicated, it does not offer to keep a track.
   2. Use a utility like Dupin to identify duplicates. You will be able to see the differences in the filenames without the laborious progress. Dupin will also be useful to identify the other scenarios also, but with some caveats I'll deal with in part 3.
2. **Duplicate entries with strange metadata conversions.**

   These can be dealt with the same as scenario 1, but with emphasis on checking the metadata and filenames carefully.
3. **Duplicate metadata and filenames**

   (Finally I'm getting round to answering the question!) These are tricky. I have had a different, and more disturbing experience than you have when picking an entry and deleting. For me the delete did **not** offer `Bin` or `Keep`. When one entry is deleted, the remaining entry now points to the file in the Bin. This is a sure fire way to lose files when you blithely empty the Bin later.

   Dupin will recognise this scenario and at first will look like it is dealing with it, but later in the workflow it will identify the double reference to the same file and recommend manual intervention for a 'highly unusual' situation. However it will still create a deletion playlist with one of the entries, though it shouldn't.

   There are three ways to manually deal with this scenario. I don't think there is any way of safely automating this without a lot of testing:

   1. If you have mistakenly consigned the file to the Bin, recover it to another location (do **not** `Put Back`). Delete the remaining database entry, and then re-import the file from your temporary location.
   2. For one of the duplicate entries, Right-click and `Show In Finder`. Copy to a temporary location. Delete both database entries and then re-import from the temp.
   3. If you are using iTunes Match, and your files are Matched or Uploaded:

      - Delete one of the duplicate entries (and allow the file to go to the Bin, that may be the only choice - like I said I don't get the option to Keep in this scenario).
      - On the remaining entry, right-click and `Remove Download`
      - Right-click and `Download` to re-add the local file.

It's disappointing to see that database management is still no further improved in Music compared to the problems I used to have in iTunes years ago. There are no consistent options to add or remove entries; there is little feedback in the import process; there seems to be some problem that allows scenario 3 to occur quite easily; there is no effort to prevent duplicate entries on import, be they by filename or metadata. The duplicate checks found in `File | Library | Show Duplicate Items` can find them well, enough, but you still have to be aware of all the above scenarios and solutions when dealing with its results.

Of course, it goes without saying to have a solid, tested backup...

Comment: I've had the other two issues occasionally, but if a song is imported that is already there, there should be no actual change.  Long ago, I would get a "this is already there, sure you want to import it?" (in some cases even when things were different).  Anyway, your info is useful, but doesn't answer the problem of having to do it one title at a time.

Comment: Yeah, just updated to recognise that regrettable conclusion. I don't think it's safe to try and automate this. The inbuilt dupe checker and / or Dupin will identify the wrong-uns, but I think sorting it manually is the only option I feel comfortable with.

Comment: RE "still no further improved"—bugs I reported years ago to Apple are still there.  Every sync to iPad or iPhone copies hundreds of songs that have not changed, yet sometimes _doesn't_ copy songs that have changed.  My sister is the artist on one album, yet she does not appear in the "artist" list, though her Album is on the Albums list.  And many more sync problems.